# In Pandoc, how do I add a newline between authors through the YAML metablock without modifying the template?

Tags: latex, yaml, newline, pandoc

I am trying to add a a couple of authors to a report I am writing. Preferably, the second author would appear on a new line after the first. I know I can modify the template to add a new field or the multiple author example given in the Pandoc readme. However, I wonder if there is any character I can use to insert a new line between authors directly in the metablock. So far I have tried `\newline`, `\\`, `|` with newline and space, `<br>`, `<div></div>`, and making the author list a string with newline or double spaces between author names, but nothing has worked. My desired output is pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't in the YAML metadata formatting (for which there are numerous [ways to have multiline strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699210/214446)), but that the LaTeX `\author` command strips the newlines. But for PDF output (with LaTeX) you can do:

```
---
title: mytitle
author: '\protect\parbox{\textwidth}{\protect\centering Author: 1\\ Author: 2\\ Author 3}'
---

body text
```

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense, thanks. Do you also know how to include a colon in the author name? So that the first line would read `Author 1` and the second line `Supervisor: Author 2`. When I try to quote or escape it, quotations marks are either included in the output or pandoc thinks I have a `Supervisor:` meta tag.

Comment: if you want to use colons, you have to wrap the YAML value in quotes, updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can go with a simple list to achieve this.

```
---
title:  'Any title comes here'
author:
- Author One
- Author Two
---
```

Another way is to rely on the title block that has a slightly different syntax.

```
% Any title comes here
% author(s) (separated by semicolons)
% date
```

Find additional variants in the [metadata-block section](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#metadata-blocks) of the pandoc manual.